# Regex to match the string until character occured, unless it's enclosed within quotes

Tags: regex

Assuming a QueryString that looks like: `$filter=Name eq "Demo"&project=10`

I would like to use groups to get the value of the `$filter`.
This can be done with the following regex:

`\$filter=(?P<group>[^&]*)`

However, when the filter looks like `$filter=Name eq "De&mo"&project=10` the Regex does not work anymore because it matches the `&` sign that enclosed within `"`.

How shoud this regex be adapted so that the full `$filter` is retrieved?

Kind regards

Comment: Programming language? `(?P<Group>` can be PCRE.

Comment: Sidenote: why does your querystring look like that? Shouldn't the spaces be `%20`s?

Comment: I can replace that myself so that's not a problem. It will be in .NET but I'm testing it in `https://regex101.com/#` with a Python syntax.

Comment: You may be better off using a querystring parser. So unless there are unknown constraints imposed upon you or you are doing this as an intellectual exercise, I'd suggest using a more pointed tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex to match and consule all quoted string in the query parameter `$filter`:

```
\$filter=((?:[^"&]*"[^"]*")*[^"&]*)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eI0lY4/2)